# Integrating web3 from Metamask in React

Tags: web3js, metamask, react

Having trouble integrating web3 from Metamask in React.
Metamask version: web3@1.0.0-beta.34

```
import Web3 from 'web3'

let web3;

window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    if (typeof window.web3 !== 'undefined') {        
        web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
    } else {
        // No web 3 provider
        console.log("Please install Metamask");
    }    
});

export default web3;
```

Getting the following error:

```
window is not defined
ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at Object../lib/getWeb3.js (lib/getWeb3.js:5:0)
```

Comment: This problem is not specific to Ethereum. The problem is that `window` is not defined. I suspect you are running this script server-side. That probably has something to do with it. You'll probably get better answers if you ask your question on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs)

Comment: @Henk, you are correct, the OP is running the script on the server-side. Here is my question to you. What is the purpose of `web3`? Does it not allow us to interact with ethereum nodes? Chances are nobody is running Metamask on their browser, so how do we make dapps for people who don't use Metamask? Hmm, let's see there is React, Next.js and those engineers using these technologies for making dapps available to the non-Metamask, non-Rinkeby using world will run into these issues from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

Question:
Does your script run on the client side or on the server side?
If on the server side - then you can not access window object.

If on the client side - look at this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43220331/is-the-window-object-of-react-synthetic

Comment: I don't think it matters, OP needed to refactor his conditional to `(typeof window !== 'undefined' && typeof window.web3 !== 'undefined')`, then his first return would have taken care of being in the browser, his else was left empty and OP needed to deal with the case that OP is on server-side more or less like so: `const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider()`. Notice use of `web3` and `providers` all over the place? Sounds ethereum related to me.